# How this JavaScript call stack skip the conditions and execute the rest?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack

```js
function countdown(x) {
  console.log(x + " A");
  if (x == 0) {
    console.log("Done!");
    //return;
  } else {
    console.log(x + "...");
    countdown(x - 1); // Every time when it reaches here, coundown(x-1 ) is added to call stack, right?
    console.log(x + " B");
  }
  console.log(x + " C");
}

countdown(2);
```

Output:

```
2 A
2...
1 A
1...
0 A
Done!
0 C
1 B
1 C
2 B
2 C
```

Correct me if my understanding is wrong, Every time the code comes to the line `countdown(x-1)` in the `else` condition, `countdown(x-1)` is added to the call stack, right? So, After the condition is finished executing, it displays `Done!` and start executing the call stack. If I uncomment the `return`, when it reaches `return` it will directly jump out of the function and start executing the call stack, hence `'0 C'` will not be console.logged.

My question is, how come the call stack function skip `'A'` and `if else` condition and executes only line `'B'` and `'C'`. Since it's also part of the function `countdown()`, it should be executed too, right?

Please if can, explain line by line what's happening here.

Comment: A is never skipped ...there's a 2A, 1A and 0A, so it'e never skipped ... so the only time B is skipped is when the argument to the function is 0

Comment: no, the `countdown(x-1)` is executed immediately, and only when it is finished the code after it executes

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help you understand the sequence of events

```js
function countdown(x) {
    var log = s => console.log(" ".repeat(8-4*x) + s);
    log(x + " A");
    if (x == 0) {
        log("Done!");
        //return;
    } else {
        log(x + "...");
        log('calling countdown(' + (x - 1) + ')');
        countdown(x - 1);
        log('countdown(' + (x - 1) + ') has returned');
        log(x + " B");
    }
    log(x + " C");
}

countdown(2);
```

Comment: So, every time when it reaches to the line `countdown(x-1)`, it doesn't jump and run the `countdown()` function, instead, it goes to the next line and put the rest of the statements to the call stack, right? so, call stack doesn't hold the `countdown()` function itself but the values of rest of the statements?

Comment: @AmeenAhsan - no, that's what you keep saying in your question, stop thinking that way ... look at the indentation of the output, that shows you which "iteration" of the function it is in

Comment: If javascript worked the way you said, then you couldn't use the result of a call to a function, because the function wouldn't run until the end of the current function - it'd be impossible to use

Comment: JS is an interpreted language and it goes line by line executing the code, right? So, it goes from the first line to the last line one by one and adding the none executed statement to the call stack? is my understanding of call stack wrong?

Comment: yes, you misunderstand the point of the call stack - again, think of a function that returns a value - your model would be pointless

Answer (score 0):

The concept to understand here is that when a sync function is executed the system waits for a result.

So if a function is nested and calls itself like in your example, it will go like:

- countdown(2) waits for countdown(1)
- countdown(1) waits for countdown(0)
- countdown(0) sends its result
- countdown(1) continues and send result
- countdown(2) continues and send result

Here is the full chain of events:

- `countdown(2)` is executed
- outputs `2 A`
- goes into `if => else` statement
- outputs `2...`
- `countdown(1)` is executed
- outputs `1 A`
- goes into `if => else` statement
- outputs `1...`
- `countdown(0)` is executed
- outputs `0 A`
- goes into `if` statement
- outputs `Done!`
- goes out of `if` statement
- outputs `0 C`
- returns result to `countdown(1)`
- `countdown(1)` continues its execution
- outputs `1 B`
- out of `if => else` statement
- outputs `1 C`
- returns result to `countdown(2)`
- `countdown(2)` continues its execution
- outputs `2 B`
- out of `if => else` statement
- outputs `2 C`